# C# Split function problem

Tags: c#, split

```
string value = "L3 ABCD L4 3501% L5 20%,L3 EFGH L4 17260% L5 20%,L3 IJKL L4 2051% L5 20%,L3 MNOP L4 2621% L5 20%,L3 QRST L4 45325% L5 20% L2 40%";
```

I am trying

```
string[] splitvalues = value.Split();
```

then using a switch to find out whether it is L2, L3, L4, L5

But value at L5 is fetching "20%,L3"

---

The code is:

```
string[] splitvalues = value.Split();

for (int i = 0; i < splitvalues .Length; i = i + 2)
{
    String id = splitvalues [i];
    switch (id)
    {
        case "L3":
            Name = splitvalues [i + 1];
            break;
        case "L4":
            Number1.FromString(splitvalues [i + 1]);
            break;
        case "L5":
            Number2.FromString(splitvalues [i + 1]);
            break;
        case "L2":
            Number3.FromString(splitvalues [i + 1]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to split. You probably use whitespace, so it's normal that asfter L5 you find _20%,L3_

Comment: @Andras Zoltan: [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) with no arguments defaults to splitting at [white-space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx).

Comment: @Marco - I was thinking the same - so I think ',' is possibly wanted here

Comment: @dtb - yeah I just looked up and realised :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] arr = value.Replace("," , " ").Split(' ');
```

Comment: You don't need to call both Replace and Split, because Split can do the same in one call. Moreover Replace is bad, because it will produce garbage string.

Comment: @Artemix: I don't change my post because it should become like yours. So +1 for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Split() without parameters splits string by space chars by default. If you want to split the string by other chars you should use overload that accepts list of separator characters:

```
string[] splitvalues = value.Split(' ', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Split() without any parameters only splits on Spaces, so splitValues[5] as '20%L3' is correct.

Can you clarify your question to describe what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting on space, but you also have some commas in the string:

"L3 ABCD L4 3501% L5 **20%,L3** EFGH L4 17260% L5 **20%,L3** IJKL L4 2051% L5 **20%,L3** MNOP L4 2621% L5 **20%,L3** QRST L4 45325% L5 20% L2 40%"

Remove the commas and you should be good to go.

If you can't modify the string, then split on whitespace and commas.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Add this in code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;;
```

program

```
        string value = "L3 ABCD L4 3501% L5 20%,L3 EFGH L4 17260% L5 20%,L3 IJKL L4 2051% L5 20%,L3 MNOP L4 2621% L5 20%,L3 QRST L4 45325% L5 20% L2 40%";
        string[] splitvalues = value.Split(',');
        List<string> outP = new List<string>();
        foreach (string s in splitvalues)
        {
            string[] innerSplit = s.Split();
            //use this 'innerSplit' variable for furture coding...
            outP.AddRange(innerSplit);
        }
```

Comment: Microsoft discourages use of untyped ArrayLists: "The .NET Framework class library contains several new generic collection classes in the System.Collections.Generic namespace. These should be used whenever possible instead of classes such as ArrayList in the System.Collections namespace.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sbxh9x2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `L(\d+)\s([^,\s]+)`, e.g.:

```
var result =    
    Regex.Matches(input, @"L(\d+)\s([^,\s]+)").OfType<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(k => int.Parse(k.Groups[1].Value), v => v.Groups[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your data is supposed to be split twice, ',' appears to be your record seperator and ' ' appears to be your field seperator;

To use this data you probably want to use split the rows and then use a regex on the lines

```
Regex fieldRegex=new Regex("(?<key>.*?)\s(?<value>.*?)");
string value = "L3 ABCD L4 3501% L5 20%,L3 EFGH L4 17260% L5 20%,L3 IJKL L4 2051% L5 20%,L3 MNOP L4 2621% L5 20%,L3 QRST L4 45325% L5 20% L2 40%"; 
string[] lines= value.Split(',');
foreach (var line in lines) {
  matches=fieldRegex.Matches(line);
  foreach (var match in matches.OfType(Match)) {
     string key=match.Groups["key"].Value;
     string value=match.Groups["value"].Value;
     switch (key) {
       case "L3":  
          Name = value;
          break;  
       case "L4":  
          Number1.FromString(value);  
          break;  
      case "L5":  
          Number2.FromString(value);  
          break;  
      case "L2":  
          Number3.FromString(value);  
          break;  
     }  
  }
}
```